# Can TLS 1.3 be enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2008-r2

Can TLS 1.3 be enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security_Adoption) the TLS 1.3 is not supported by Windows Server 2008 R2, and knowing that end of support for Windows Server 2008 R2 was on 1/14/2020, there is no chance to enable it.